# grabbing a new random number for each variable

Tags: javascript

how would I go about using the same variable, rand, for a random number, but attach that to multiple variables that will each have a different rand?

so it would be like

```
function draw(){
enemy.y = rand;
enemy.y2 = rand;
enemy.y3 = rand;
enemy.y4 = rand;
enemy.y5 = rand;
enemy.y6 = rand;
enemy.y7 = rand;
enemy.y8 = rand;
enemy.y9 = rand;
}
```

except maybe cleaner than that, like enemy.this = rand later after I smooth out some of the code.
So how would I get rand to be different for each variable, while still using the variable name rand?

Comment: i would make rand a function call returning a random variable.

Comment: Using the "same" variable to hold "different" random values doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

One of the hack can be define rand as window object propery and set the getter for it like this

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "rand", {
    get: function(){ return parseInt(Math.random() * 10); }
})
```

which will return a random value on every use of `rand` variable
But i don't think this is a good idea and will not recommend to do it like this.
Instead make `rand` a function that returns random value on each call like this

```
var rand = function(){
    return  parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
}
```

and use `rand()` to get random value each time